# Is it effecient to remove and insert elements to begining of a list?

Tags: python, list, data-structures, stack

I found this on the python site.

> It is also possible to use a list as a queue, where the first element
>   added is the first element retrieved (“first-in, first-out”); however,
>   lists are not efficient for this purpose. While appends and pops from
>   the end of list are fast, doing inserts or pops from the beginning of
>   a list is slow (because all of the other elements have to be shifted
>   by one)

This is OK but my question is then, Is it efficient to remove or insert elements to beginning of a list?

Comment: Your quote already contains the answer: "doing inserts or pops from the beginning of a list is slow" (A `pop` is a `remove` that returns the removed item).

Comment: has the part of the docs in your not already answered the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have noted, your quote from the docs explicitly says it is not efficient.

If you want an efficient double-ended queue structure, you should use [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Answer (score 1):

Like the documentation says when you insert or remove elements from the beginning of a list all the other elements have to be shifted and it's therefore an `O(n)` operation on the size of the list.

Note however that Python uses reference semantic and a list indeed contains only **pointers** to the elements, thus to do the shifting only the pointers are moved around and not whole objects. Therefore while being an `O(n)` operation the constant is very small.

For example in C++ that uses instead "value semantic" an `std::vector` (the container most similar to Python list) contains the objects themselves and to shift elements the operation is more complex and can possibly require copying of large amount of data even for few elements (if they're big).

Answer (score 1):

There is a specially devised container called `deque` in the collections module that inserts and pops elements more efficiently on both ends. It otherwise uses the same methods as a list, so the implementation of a queue object that should remained unchanged with out any side effects, save for using a deque instead of a list.

Comment: `deque` operations are *more* efficient at the start, *less* efficient at the end. Otherwise there would be no need for anything else.